# Output and speed of own defined power() function is different than inbuilt python pow() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write my own `power()` function in python but when i compared it with python inbuilt `pow()` function in output and speed. I found that my code is 6-7 times slower and last 3-4 digits of output is different as compared to output of inbuilt pow() function for floating point numbers. I am totally new to python and unable to find the explanation. plz help

**Note**:- I have used binomial expansion for calculating fractional power and Binary Exponent for integral power

**Here is my code**-

```
def power(x, n):
    if not(isinstance(x, complex) or isinstance(n, complex)):
        res = 1
        if n == 0 and x != 0:
            return 1
        
        if n > 0 and x == 0:
            return 0
        
        if n < 0 and x == 0:
            return "Zero Division Error"
            
        if n == 0 and x == 0:
            return "Indeterminate Form" 
        
        if n == 1:
            return x
            
        if n > 0 and n < 1:
            return fpower(x,n)
                
        if n > 1 and n < 2:
            return x*fpower(x,n-1)
            
        if n == -1:
            return 1/x
                
        if n < 0 and n > -1:
            return fpower(x,n)
            
        if n < -1 and n > -2:
            return 1/x*fpower(x,n+1)
            
        
        if n >= 2:
            f_p = n - n // 1
            t_x = x
            n //= 1
            if n%2:
                res = x
                n //= 2
            else:
                res = 1
                n //= 2
            while n != 1 and n > 1:
                if n%2:
                    res *= x*x
                x *= x
                n //= 2
            res *= x*x
            if f_p == 0:
                return res
            elif f_p < 1:
                return res*fpower(t_x,f_p)
            
        if n <= -2:
            f_p = n+(-n // 1)
            t_x = x
            n = -n // 1
            if n%2:
                res = 1/x
                n = n // 2
            else:
                res = 1
                n = n // 2
            while n != 1 and n > 1:
                if n%2:
                    res *= 1/x*1/x
                x *= x
                n //= 2
            res *= 1/x*1/x
            if f_p == 0:
                return res
            elif f_p > -1:
                return res*fpower(t_x,f_p)

#function to calculate fractional power
def fpower(x, n):
    pwr = 0
    sign = 1
    t_n = n
    if x < 0:
        x *= -1
        sign = -1
    while x > 2:
        x = x/2
        pwr += 1
    if x >1:
        pwr *= n
        n *= -1
        x = 1/x-1
    elif x < 0.5 and x != 0:
        x = sign*1/x
        return fpower(x,-n)
    elif x != 0:
        x -= 1
    
    
    res = 0
    step = 1
    coeff = 1
    i = 0
    while step > 1e-20:
        step = coeff*power(x,i)
        res += step
        coeff *= (n-i)/(i+1)
        i += 1
        if step < 0:
            step *= -1
    mp = res*power(2,pwr)
    if sign < 0:
        pi = 3.141592653589793
        real = mp*cos(t_n*pi)
        img = mp*sin(t_n*pi)
        if img != 0:
            return complex(real,img)   
        else:
            return real
    else:
        return mp
```

**Output Comparison:**

Inbuilt fn -

```
pow(89,99.354)
4.7829376579139805e+193
```

Own fn -

```
power(89,99.354)
4.7829376579139765e+193
```

**Speed Comparison:**

Inbuilt fn time -

```
pow(89,99.354)
0.00026869773864746094
```

Own fn time-

```
power(89,99.354)
0.0023398399353027344
```

Comment: Python's `pow` function is presumably implemented in C - it should be totally expected that your implementation is slower. As for less accurate results on floating point numbers, that's also unsurprising, it is either because your algorithm is just less numerically stable, or just because your algorithm not being implemented in C means it cannot take advantage of the CPU using higher precision floating point numbers for intermediate operations. So I don't think there is anything to help you with here.

Comment: Is the accuracy any better if you use `math.pi`? and `decimal.Decimal`?

Comment: Actually, my aim was to built a power function without using any module...just using the core functionality of python...so i didn't try with decimal and math.pi

Comment: Hmmm, I would consider those to be part of *core* Python.

Comment: @wwii Sorry... I was just trying to write in the same way as it would have been written in C.. without using any module....but I am not smart enough to do so..

Comment: @kaya3...thank you for your help....Now I understood the reason behind my question

Comment: A result correct to 13 significant digits is excellent. You may be assuming that computer floating-point arithmetic works with mathematical entities that are capable of infinite precision, and so it should not matter what language the solution is written in. But that is not true. All floating-point computation is approximate, and it is very hard to write code that limits roundoff error and produces better results. When you use a high-level language like Python you essentially delegate such functions to specialists working in C.

Comment: Because Python is much slower than C.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can be said here. First of all, many Python standard library functions will be implemented in C, not in Python, so they will be faster. This makes sense, as the standard library will be called by a lot of code lots of times, so it pays off to implement such often-used code in a faster language.

Along with that goes additional optimization: this code is called so often that, besides implementing it in C, it makes sense to optimize this code. Compared to baseline Python, this includes writing "faster" C, but also what you get out of the box from your C compiler.

Some cursory research doesn't suggest this is the case, but exponentiation, as a common math operation, could also have some hardware acceleration that requires you to use specific intructions of the architecture you're running on - which you won't easily (if at all) be able to utilize in pure Python.

Then there's the matter of algorithms; once we leave the language difference aside, there are different ways to compute exponentiation, and without contrary evidence you should not assume that you have chosen the most efficient one. From you pointing out your algorithms it seems you have carefully chosen which ones to use, but still - when you're posing aquestion like this, don't simply assume you made an equally good choice as the standard library of a **looks at Wikipedia** 30 year old language.

Finally, don't forget that benchmarking methodology also plays a role in questions like this in general. a 6-7 times difference won't go away by changing your methodology, but it's worth remembering that testing your code against a very small number of inputs may not be representative of your code's performance in general, and different inputs will be representative for the built-in pow.

That's my thoughts on performance; as for accuracy, floating point errors can simply add up. As soon as you perform more than one operation on a decimal number, this will happen. (And remember, in general the first operation is representing the number in binary (IEEE 754) floating point format.) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) gives the example if squaring 0.1; 0.1 can not be represented precisely in binary, so you get your first rounding error here. As a result, squaring it will give you a less precise result than the best approximation for 0.01. As far as I can tell, you're not trying to comensate for roundign errors, and you're using a loop, so noticeable rounding errors are inevitable.